# Filter realm objects to only get one (distinct) object by attribute

Tags: swift, realm, distinct, nspredicate

Let me explain first cause title may be a bit confusing.

Say I have this realm objects of type Movie:

```
Movie1(id: 0, genre: "horror")

Movie2(id: 1, genre: "horror")

Movie3(id: 3, genre: "sci-fi")
```

What I need to do is get the first for every genre (in this case `Movie1` and `Movie3`)

I'd like to do it w/o loops using only `realm` + `NSPredicate`, so the performance is better, but I'm a bit stuck there...

So far what I got is this:

```
Realm().objects(Movie.self).sorted(byKeyPath: id, ascending: true)
.value(forKeyPath: "@distinctUnionOfObjects.genre")
```

This returns me an array with `("horror", "sci-fi")` and I can't really figure what should be the next step. If I try to do a:

```
 .filter("genre IN %@", arrayWithDistinctGenres)
```

it will return me all the objects.

Probably it's simple but I cannot figure how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of Realm Swift 3.1 you can do `let movies = realm.objects(Movie.self).sorted(by: ["id", true]).distinct(by: ["genre"])`, which will select the first `Movie` of each genre using the sort order applied before the distinct operation.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thanks a lot man. I was with realm 3.0.1 but after update to 3.1.1 it worked, saving me some lines of code and avoiding the for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter by one genre at a time. Something like this

```
let genres = realm.objects(Genres.self)
let movies = realm.objects(Movie.self).sorted(byKeyPath: id, ascending: true)

for genre in genres {
    let firstInThisGenre = movies.filter({ $0.genreId == genre.id }).first
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I have now and i wanted to avoid (if possible) that loop. I guess it's not possible then, thanks.

Comment: using something like MySQL you could use a GROUP BY in the query to do this without the loop but I don't think that is possible in realm

Comment: Ok. Thanks again