# Realm query for getting first of sequence

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a table that has data like below:

```
id | collection

1  | aaa
2  | aaa
3  | bbb
4  | bbb
5  | aaa
6  | ccc
7  | ddd
8  | ddd
9  | ddd
```

Now I want to get the first indexes of same value of `collection` in consecutive order.
Result should be:

> 1, 3, 5, 6, 7

Is there a realm query for this?

Comment: Check this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742646/filter-realm-objects-to-only-get-one-distinct-object-by-attribute

Comment: You should edit your question to include your actual Realm model definitions, that would make writing an actual query much easier.

Comment: Thanks @VirenMalhan! Is it possible to get indexes only?